# Do i need to consider higher dimensional boxes while trying to find minimum distance from an n-dimensional point to an n-dimensional box?

Tags: geometry

Do I need to consider higher-{sub}dimensional(>= 3 dimensions but, <= parent dimensions) boxes(cube(3-cube), Tesseract(4-cube), Penteract(5-cube), Hexeract(6-cube), etc.) while trying to find the minimum distance from an n-dimensional point, in a cartesian space, to an n-dimensional [hyperbox/hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube), other than a vertex or an edge or a face of the hyperbox/hypercube?

For example, say I want to find the minimum distance from a point in a 4 dimensional {cartesian}-space to a Tesseract(4-cube) in that same space. I know that to find the minimum distance from any arbitrary point to the Tesseract(4-cube) I, at least, need to look at the distances of the point to each vertex, edges & faces of Tesseract(4-cube). But, when I try to think of the higher-dimensional sub-box(cube), I come to this logic/understanding/statement "the distance of a point to a cube is minimum the distance from each vertex, edge, and face to the point, since I only need to look at the surface(which is (strictly)in a 2-d plane) of the hyperbox/hypercube. I.e. a hyperbox/hypercube's surface is made up of points/vertices, edges & (2-d)faces", which leads me back to square 1.

So what I am asking is, do I need to look at higher(> 2)-{sub}dimensional sub-boxes which are in the space of an n-dimensional hyper-box/hypercube, while trying to find the minimum distance of a point in that same n-dimensional space to the hyper-box/hypercube? Is my reasoning in the above paragraph correct, while reaching at the conclusion that, "I only need to consider objects of dimension less than 3, while trying to find minimum distance"? And, is this conclusion correct, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I do not think that you can avoid the n dimension space. I think that the process should involve a several steps - find a close vertex. Verify that there is no close edge and than that there is no close face.

Comment: So u mean, I should also look at 3d(or even higher dimensional)-subobjects like a cube in a Tesseract(4-cube)? but to find the distance of a cube from any arbitrary point in 4d-space, i'd have to measure the distance from all the 8 vertices, 12 edges & 6 faces. which reduces my search space(in 4d) to "vertices", "edges" & "faces"(same as 3d). is the procedure for measuring the distance between a point & an object in 4 or higher dimensions different than in 3 dimensions? does the euclidean method of measuring distance between points not work in higher dimensions?

Comment: I am not sure you can do the job in lower dimensions - to do that you will need to select a projection from higher dimensions to lower. after finding the distance to the vertices you may filter out some of the vertices to focus the search only to the relevant pair of vertices and than to faces and then to cubes... in 1D you have vertices. in 2d vertices and edges. in 3D vertices, edges and faces. in 4D vertices, edges, faces, and "cubes"... I hope this explains the need to work in the n dimensions space.